# Differential Equation of Type Ricatti as part of Short Rate Model

Tags: interest-rates, differential-equations

I currently despair of the following solution of a differiental equation (Ricatti Type) as part of a short rate model:

$$
B_t=\frac{1}{2}aB^2+bB-1 
$$
First I am "guessing" a particular solution 
$$ c \in \mathbb{R} $$
as its derivative is zero. That is straightforward and I get e.g.
$$
-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2+2a}}{a}=s
$$

I call $$ \sqrt{b^2+2a} = k $$ from now on.

For a general solution y I set $$y=s+u$$ and insert y into the initial equation.

$$
s'+u'=\frac{1}{2}a(s+u)^2+b(s+u)-1
$$
As s'= 0:
$$
u'=\frac{1}{2}as^2+\frac{1}{2}au^2+asu+bs+bu-1
$$
We already know that 
$$
u'=\frac{1}{2}as^2+bs-1=0
$$
thus we are left with
$$
u'=\frac{1}{2}au^2+asu+bu
$$
We now can set
$$
z=\frac{1}{u}
$$
Therefore,
$$
u'=-\frac{z'}{z^2}
$$
Inserting this into the equation delivers:
$$
z_t+z(as+b)-\frac{1}{2}a
$$

which is a linear DGL with the solution:
$$
z=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}a \int\limits_{t}^{T} exp(k(T-t)) d\tau+C}{exp(k(T-t))}
$$

Furthermore (see definition of k above):
$$
as+b=k 
$$

Now I have to resubstitute  to find y (which is B) with:
$$
y=\frac{1}{z}+s
$$
So I have:
$$
y=\frac{exp(k(T-t))}{-\frac{1}{2}a \int\limits_{t}^{T} exp(k(T-t)) d\tau+C}+s
$$
And I now that 
$$
B(T,T)=y(T,T)=0
$$
in order to find C.

Does anyone already spot any mistake I might have made, because no matter what I do I never obtain the solution proposed, being:
$$
B(t,T)=\frac{2(exp(k(T-t))-1)}{(b+k)(exp(k(T-t))-1)+2k}
$$
Or if no mistake is spotted, can somebody carry me over the finish line. I tries everything, also by inserting numbers, but still...something is  off.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!
Kev